# Kubernetes, expose all ports

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, kubernetes-service

I’d like to use Kubernetes, as I’m reading everywhere : “Kubernetes is, without a doubt, the leading container orchestrator available today.“

My issue here is with the networking. I need to expose external IP to each of the pods. I need that my pods are seen as if they were traditional VM or HW servers. Meaning that I need all the ports to be exposed.

What I see so far, is I can expose only a limited list of ports.

Am I correct ? Or do I miss something ?

Cheers,
Raoul

Comment: check [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

Comment: If VMs or bare-metal servers are a better match for your application, by all means, use them.  (There are some [tag:docker] questions that want to listen to thousands of TCP ports, and the usual answer is to disable Docker's networking layer; that's even harder in Kubernetes.)

Comment: Well, I need the containers feature of instant deleta and instant spawn. I'm not looking at absoulty use Kubernetes, I'm just looking for the good orchestration tool to span and delete remote containers. I've heard about K8s, so my question was more, It is a good tool for me or what other containers provisioning tool do you recommend?

Comment: @RaoulDebaze Could you shed some light on why it is needed to have _all_ ports exposed? Does your application expect incoming traffic on random ports?

Comment: No not random ports effectively. But at least a range of 100 continuous port. I was more thinking on how can I use K8S and make my application feel the most possible as if it were on normal servers

Comment: @RaoulDebaze, in case of continious ports you can generate service yaml with the script. For example with something like [this one](https://github.com/nkolchenko/technocore/blob/master/K8s_NodePort_mapping_generator.py). Have you achieved your goal, btw? Kamol is correct about the `NodePort`.

Comment: Were you able to expose the whole container with all its ports? I would like to do the same for internal cluster network.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes, you will need [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to communicate with pods. To expose the pods outside the Kubernetes cluster, you can use k8s service of [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - 
      port: 8080
      nodePort: 30000
      name: my-port-8080
    -
      port: 8081
      nodePort: 30001
      name: my-port-8081
    -
      port: 8082
      nodePort: 30002
      name: my-port-8081
```

Then you will be able to reach your pods at, `https://<node-ip>:nodePort`.
For in-cluster communication, you can use service's dns: `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc:PORT`

**Update:**

Take a look at this guide: [Using a Service to Expose Your App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but here you expose only one port. Me, I need that my single container in my part has an external IP, and being seen by external world as if it was a standalone VM or server.

Comment: Here, `ports[]` is an array field, you can add multiple ports. You can also try the [Ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.
Pods are not "real" servers, their are rather application-instances with open ports.

Because of the docker- and kubernetes-network-implementation it's not possible to build what you want.

I don't know your use-case, but maybe you are not looking for kubernetes.